# Add new lines when concatenating strings?

Tags: r, string

I have following sentences that I would like to combine together, but I want the second sentence to start out as a new paragraph:

```
Sentence 1: Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office.
Sentence 2: Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R.
```

I would like the two sentences to look like the following:

```
Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office.

Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R.
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
sen.1 <- "Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office."
sen.2 <- "Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R."
paragrah <- cat(sen.1, sen.2)

paragraph
Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office. Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cat(sen.1, "\n", sen.2)`. to print to console, to save to variable `capture.output(cat(sen.1, "\n", sen.2))`

Comment: `cat(sen.1, sen.2, sep = '\n\n')`

Comment: @snoram: Hm, that did not work from my end : )

Comment: @alistaire: That worked! Could you write that using the "Answer Your Question" button so that I can select your answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to insert two newline characters (`\n`):

```r
sen.1 <- "Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office."
sen.2 <- "Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R."

# for printing directly, use `cat`
cat(sen.1, sen.2, sep = "\n\n")
#> Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office.
#> 
#> Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R.

# for saving as a variable for future printing, use `paste`
paragraph <- paste(sen.1, sen.2, sep = "\n\n")

# the print method of character vectors doesn't respect newlines...
paragraph
#> [1] "Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office.\n\nConclusion: Therefore, we should learn R."

# ...so use `cat`
cat(paragraph)
#> Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office.
#> 
#> Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `writeLines` function, which will print separated strings to different lines.

```
sen.1 <- "Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office."
sen.2 <- "Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R."

writeLines(c(sen.1, " ", sen.2))
Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office.

Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R.
```

Answer (score 1):

`\n` for a linebreak in `cat`, but note that it returns no value - just prints to console, apparently you can work around that with `capture.output`...

```
paragrah  <- capture.output(cat(sen.1, "\n\n", sen.2))
paragrah

[1] "Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office. "
[2] ""                                                              
[3] " Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R." 

# Or simply
cat(sen.1, "\n\n", sen.2)
Premise: R is very useful for automating tasks at the office. 

 Conclusion: Therefore, we should learn R.
```

Comment: you can also save to a file with `cat`

Comment: `cat(sen.1, "", sen.2, sep = "\n")`  would make more sense.  Plus you won't get that extra space in the third line.

Comment: The default separator for `cat` is `" "`, which is why there are those extra spaces inserted after line 1 and before line 3.

Comment: I would delete my answer, since it adds little to @alistaire but these great comments deserve to be seen.